# Deploy a rails app to a private server using AZK

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ubuntu-14.04, azk

I'm trying this time to deploy my rails app on a Scaleway VC1 server (Ubuntu 14.04LTS / 2 x86 64bits Core / 2Go RAM).

I'm using AZK, and in particular the azukiapp/deploy docker image (version `0.0.7`).

I unfortunatly encounter a problem during deployment, as this log suggest :

```
| > azk deploy -vvv

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************

Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/xxx': 
ok: [default]

TASK [configure : Create user and add him to docker group] *********************
changed: [default]

TASK [configure : Accept azk terms of use] *************************************
changed: [default]

TASK [configure : Ensure /etc/resolver path exists] ****************************
ok: [default]

TASK [configure : Ensure required directories exists] **************************
changed: [default] => (item=/home/git/d1fdb3d.git)
changed: [default] => (item=/home/git/d1fdb3d)
changed: [default] => (item=/home/git/.ssh)
changed: [default] => (item=/home/git/bin)

TASK [configure : Ensure authorized_keys exists] *******************************
changed: [default]

TASK [configure : Create git repository] ***************************************
changed: [default]

TASK [configure : Ensure repository permissions] *******************************
changed: [default]

TASK [configure : Apply templates] *********************************************
changed: [default] => (item={u'dest': u'/home/git/bin/azk-start', u'src': u'azk-start.j2', u'mode': u'0755', u'owner': u'git'})
changed: [default] => (item={u'dest': u'/home/git/bin/git-checkout', u'src': u'git-checkout.j2', u'mode': u'0755', u'owner': u'git'})
changed: [default] => (item={u'dest': u'/home/git/bin/rollback', u'src': u'rollback.j2', u'mode': u'0755', u'owner': u'git'})
changed: [default] => (item={u'dest': u'/home/git/bin/versions', u'src': u'versions.j2', u'mode': u'0755', u'owner': u'git'})
changed: [default] => (item={u'dest': u'/home/git/d1fdb3d.git/hooks/post-receive', u'src': u'post-receive.j2', u'mode': u'0755', u'owner': u'git'})
changed: [default] => (item={u'dest': u'/etc/dbus-1/system.d/Upstart.conf', u'src': u'Upstart.conf.j2', u'mode': u'0644', u'owner': u'root'})
changed: [default] => (item={u'dest': u'/etc/init/azk-agent.conf', u'src': u'azk-agent.conf.j2', u'mode': u'0644', u'owner': u'root'})
changed: [default] => (item={u'dest': u'/etc/init/azk-all.conf', u'src': u'azk-all.conf.j2', u'mode': u'0644', u'owner': u'root'})
changed: [default] => (item={u'dest': u'/etc/init/azk.conf', u'src': u'azk.conf.j2', u'mode': u'0644', u'owner': u'root'})
failed: [default] (item={u'dest': u'/etc/resolver/dev.azk.io', u'src': u'resolver.j2', u'mode': u'0644', u'owner': u'root'}) => {"failed": true, "item": {"dest": "/etc/resolver/dev.azk.io", "mode": "0644", "owner": "root", "src": "resolver.j2"}, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'ansible_docker0' is undefined"}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************
    to retry, use: --limit @playbooks/configure.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
default                    : ok=8    changed=6    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Seems to be related to Ansible. Should I install something on the remote server prior deployment ?

Here is the deploy part of my Azkfile.js if it helps :

```
deploy: {
        image: {docker: 'azukiapp/deploy:0.0.7'},
        mounts: {
            '/azk/deploy/src': path('.'),
            '/azk/deploy/.ssh': path('#{env.HOME}/.ssh'), // Required to connect with the remote server
            '/azk/deploy/.config': persistent('deploy-config')
        },
        scalable: {default: 0, limit: 0},
        envs: {
            GIT_REF: 'azk',
            REMOTE_HOST: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
            SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE: 'xx'
        }
    }
```

Thanks your time/help.

Comment: not really a programming related question, try over at serverfault ...

Answer (score 1):

Edouard, looks like Docker installation has not worked properly.

Please log into  your private server and check if `docker` is available and if you have a network interface called `docker0`.

Feel free to join [Azuki's channel on Gitter](https://gitter.im/azukiapp/azk) for a better support experience.